# C# Graphics object return text array

Tags: c#, graphics, right-to-left

Is it possible to get the DrawString method of C# Graphics object returns the text array just how it's rendering to the display?

e.g.

```
var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12);
var stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft) { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near};
var rectangle=new RectangleF(0, 0, 100,20);
var text = "hello this بشدة 176.48 إشعارك بأن";
var textArray= gfx.DrawStringOut(text, font, rectangle, stringFormat);
```

It should return the below image but in text representation.

[image]

Comment: No. Sounds like an x-y problem. What do you really want?!

Comment: I want the string to return the following text mentioned in the image.

Comment: I still don't understand at all.

Comment: I want to write a function which can take string as input and output the string in wrap format, like in the example I mentioned, I passed "hello this بشدة 176.48 إشعارك بأن" as input and this should return "hello this\nARABIC_STRING\n176.48\nARABIC_STRING"

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Do update the question with this info !! - I think you will have to use Graphics.MeasureText to find lengths of word until your width is filled etc..

Comment: Yes, somehow the Graphics.MeasureText is not working correctly for Arabic text.. any idea on that??

Comment: As arabic is right to left I think you need to measure thos parts separately.. Beyond that guess I don't know much..